# OpenCV light reflection reduction

Tags: java, android, opencv

i have problem with light reflection, here's the picture taken with standart camera

[image: Original Image taken with camera]

and process that i do

```
1. blur the image
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(blurred, blurred, new Size(17, 17),
    Imgproc.BORDER_ISOLATED);
2. create second empty image that using hsv
    Imgproc.cvtColor(gray0, gray0, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
3. mix the image color chanel (fromto {0,0})
    Core.mixChannels(blurredlist, graylist, fromto);
4. Threshold, Canny, and delate
Imgproc.threshold(gray0, gray0, 126, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_TRUNC);
Imgproc.Canny(gray0, gray0, 50, 70);
Imgproc.dilate(gray0, gray0, Mat.ones(new Size(3, 3), 0));
5. finding the contour
    Imgproc.findContours(gray0, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
6. magicall filter for biggest contour and stuff
```

and here is the result
[image: After Thresholding]
how can i remove the backlight or connected the broken line from detected contour?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the reflection oversaturates the pixels. There are two possible paths to take here;

**Adjust the condition**

Adjusting the condition is the easiest path. By simply controling the conditions by which the image is taken, you can remove most (if not all) difficult situations (such as these). 
Think about using polarized filters, better (eg; diffuse) lighting, better exposure settings, etc.

**Adjust the image**

The other option (eg; removing the highlights afterwards) is much more difficult. This is mostly because the oversaturation destroys a lot of data. The most common used method for this is to use HDR images, which tend to preserve a lot more data, as the images are taken at varying exposures.
In some cases the problem might occur due to the RAW conversion; but improving that is generally quite tedious.

Comment: well, i'm new to android and still learning opencv, inspired by an app shot docs https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jp.shotdocs that can detect the paper with same environment. just wondering, what method that they used ...

Comment: By the look of it; they assume that the thing you are trying to detect is square. Eg; They try to fit several lines to the data points with the best match. As in this case, three of the lines can be fitted quite easy (as you have a lot of points). The edge on the left is harder, but still possible as only the 'middle' is invisible.

Comment: yep, square detection it is ...
if the background clear and not having any reflection of light, the accuracy quite good but, a reflection near the paper make it fail to recognise the square.

Comment: If you image material is always as good as it is in your example (very nearly no background/noise) you can try to detect the lines (for example with RANSAC or HoughLines) instead of removing the reflection effect. Robust Line detection will just fill the hole because there is one consistent line that connects both sides of the hole.

Comment: i read about Houghlines before. i'll try to integrated with my code and share the result for later discussion.

Comment: @phe can you share the code for houghlines detection in android